# Attribute Error : module 'rasa_nlu.utils' has no attribute 'list_files'

Tags: python, spyder, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa

I'm using version 0.11.5 of RASA NLU and I get the Attribute error " module 'rasa_nlu.utils' has no attribute 'list_files' " in this line :

```
training_data = load_data("./training_data.json")
```

What should I do now ? Should I install a different version of RASA ? 
I'm using the Anaconda Spyder platform.

Comment: Could you use `read_json_file` instead of `load_data`?

Comment: Tried it but I get an error saying " name 'read_json_file' is not defined"

Comment: yeah.. you can have to import it. Use `from rasa.utils.io import read_json_file`

Answer (score 1):

Rasa Open Source has drastically improved since Rasa NLU 0.11.5. I would recommend checking out the [latest version](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/nlu/choosing-a-pipeline/#how-to-choose-a-pipeline), which uses the [DIET classifier](https://youtu.be/vWStcJDuOUk)